# Difference between [] and {{}} for binding state to property?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Here is an template example:

```
<span count="{{currentCount}}"></span>
<span [count]="currentCount"></span>
```

Here both of them does the same thing. Which one is preferred and why?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`[]` is for binding from a value in the parent component to an `@Input()` in the child component. It allows to pass objects.

`{{}}` is for binding **strings** in properties and HTML like

```
<div somePropOrAttr="{{xxx}}">abc {{xxx}} yz</div>
```

where the binding can be part of a string.

`()` is for binding an event handler to be called when a DOM event is fired or an `EventEmitter` on the child component emits an event

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-comp',
    template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <button (click)="notifyParent()">notify</button>
    `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output() notify = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() title;

  notifyParent() {
    this.notify.emit('Some notification');
  }
}


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [ChildComponent]
    template: `
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <child-comp [title]="childTitle" (notify)="onNotification($event)"></child-comp>
    <div>note from child: {{notification}}</div>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  childTitle = "I'm the child";

  onNotification(event) {
    this.notification = event;
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/6nhz9V?p=preview)

More details in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax

Comment: I wanted difference between [] and {{}} not [] and ().

Answer (score 9):

### Difference between string interpolation and property binding:

The main thing to understand it the following:

> Interpolation is a special syntax that Angular converts into property
>   binding. It’s a convenient alternative to property binding.

This implies that **under the hood it yields a similar outcome**. However, string interpolation has one important limitation. This is that everything within string interpolation will first be evaluated (trying to find a value from the model ts file):

- if this value cannot be found there then the value within the string interpolation will be evaluated to a string.
- If this value is found in the model the value which is found gets coerced to a string and is used.

This has some implications on how you can use the 2 methods. For example:

1. String concatenation with string interpolation:

   ```
     <img src=' https://angular.io/{{imagePath}}'/>
   ```
2. String interpolation cannot be used for anything else than strings

   ```
     <myComponent  [myInput]="myObject"></myComponent>
   ```

When `myInput` is an `@Input()` of `myComponent` and we want to pass in an object, we have to use property binding. If we were to use string interpolation the object would be turned into a string and this would be passed in as a value for `myInput`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming a little bit late after the battle :) , but, in my understanding, there is another difference which can sometimes be very important.

As its name implies "Property Binding" means that you are binding to the **property** of the HTML element "object"(which corresponds to its "objective" representation in the DOM), which is a different thing from string interpolation, which can be applied to the HTML element tag **attribute**, and which is the reason why you can only put strings in it, as you are talking to a not parsed/parseable entity.

Very often, you have a direct correspondence between both (the tag in your html has a foo attribute, which is linked to the foo property of the DOM object), but that's not a rule and you can have attributes that are not linked to properties as well as the opposite.

By the way, you have a very good answer in stack overflow which explains deeply the difference between both: [What is the difference between properties and attributes in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html)